# Keep the "dictionary as string" format when serializing

Tags: python, yaml

I have to work with the following YAML file:

```yaml
HEADER:
  properly_formated_section:
    ..
  config:
    value1: {value: 1, id: 0}
    value2: {value: 2, id: 1}
```

When deserialized, then serialized (using just yaml), I obtain the following:

```yaml
HEADER:
  properly_formated_section:
    ..
  config:
    value1:
      - value: 1
        id: 0
    value2:
      - value: 2
        if: 1
```

This causes trouble to the software after me that uses the file, so I need to keep the "dictionary as string" format.

So far, the best I could do is the following:

```yaml
HEADER:
  properly_formated_section:
    ..
  config:
    value1: '{"value": 1, "id": 0}'
    value2: '{"value": 2, "id": 1}'
```

In this case, the added single and double quotes will cause issues.

Is there a simple solution to keep this as in the original file, without the quotes? The solution needs to focus only on the `config` key and leave the others alone.

Comment: Your dictionary isn't a string, it's an object (except in the last example, which has unspecified issues). The two YAML forms are equivalent so if the software after you has "trouble" it can't really handle YAML.

Comment: The two syntaxes are equivalent in YAML. The software after you that uses the file is broken and should be taught how to parse YAML properly. (This is the principled answer, not necessarily the practical one ;))

Comment: I agree with you but I am not in capability to fix the software (the yaml file actualy has invalid tags that I need to remove before deserialization and replace after serialization ...)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are indicating PyYAML, with "just yaml", you should be not be using that
for updating YAML documents. It only supports a subset of YAML 1.1 (YAML 1.2 spec was released in 2009),
and is not good at preserving details that can be relevant for humans (and revision control systems), like
style, comments, anchor names, etc.

You should use `ruamel.yaml` instead (disclaimer: I am the author of that package):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
import yaml as pyyaml

yaml_str = """\
HEADER:
  properly_formated_section:
    a: |
       some text
    seq:
    - 1
    - 42   # thanks DA
    b: 'more text'
    c: "even more text"
    [1, 5]: PyYAML cannot handle this, even though it is even valid YAML 1.1

  config:
    value1: {value: 1, id: 0}
    value2: {value: 2, id: 1}
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
print('-----------')

try:
    pyyaml.safe_load(yaml_str)
except Exception as e:
    print('PyYAML execepted on input')
```

which gives:

```
HEADER:
  properly_formated_section:
    a: |
      some text
    seq:
    - 1
    - 42   # thanks DA
    b: 'more text'
    c: "even more text"
    [1, 5]: PyYAML cannot handle this, even though it is even valid YAML 1.1

  config:
    value1: {value: 1, id: 0}
    value2: {value: 2, id: 1}
-----------
PyYAML execepted on input
```

As you can see ruamel.yaml preserves the original layout and quoting without problem,
only requiring the setting of `.preserve_quotes` to keep existing quotes (all of which
are superfluous in this input).

What you call "dictionary as string" format, is named "flow-style mapping" in YAML parlance.